# I would like to use JS libraries, in an apex class context

Tags: javascript

We have wonderful JS libraries available, that does a lot many things.Is there anyway to leverage them in apex classes?. The context for me is to take advantage of XSL transformation files, use a JS file to apply it to my input XML doc, and get an output file, with all the rules applied (defined in the XSL file)

Comment: If your JS libraries are wrapped up in a web service, you can invoke that web service from APEX using HTTP Callouts; that said, bulkification in triggers may make repeated calls to a webservice blow up governor limits

Comment: That would be the best for me, notwithstanding the governor limits, but I only have the library files. Is there any way we could host those JS libraries as webServices, within Salesforce ? @crop1645  Appreciate you time taken to look into this.

Comment: Your question is out of my depth -- the place to look would be Heroku, part of Salesforce platform

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by Apex context but you can easily maintain the context in your javascript and the apex by "[Javascript remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm)".

It provides static Apex methods accessible on Visualforce page as well as in Javascript where you can serialize and de-serialize apex and perform the operations by maintaining the state on both sides Jabascript and the Apex.

So, it would help in maintaining the State or the Context to a limit.

Comment: Javascript remoting are Apex methods, called in a Javascript context. I was lookin the other way round. ie Javascript methods called in Apex context (classes, triggers.).